# using for loop variable in function python

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I'm building an application that does the following things:

- Get hosts from .txt file and place them into a list
- Download the headers for each website and put them into another list
- Print the line containing  a specific word into a logfile containing a timestamp, the specific line and the url which belongs to that.

Everything is actually working fine, but I cannot seem to pass on the url that is beeing checked to the other function so that it can be used.

The code in this link: http://pastebin.com/630FrspN

Will actually print the same url each entry in the logfile... If I put the logfile(websiteheaders,url) into the for loop, it will work but it will print an entry in the logfile as many times as I have urls in my host file.

I somehow need to pass on the "url" that is beeing checked in the for loop to the logfile function...

Probaly an easy answer, but I cannot seem to find it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think this below code is the most relevant.

```
def headerophalen(websites):

    for url in websites:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            headers = str(response.info())
            websiteheaders.extend(headers.splitlines())
        except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
            print "Error opening URL: ", url, "HTTP Errorcode: ", error.code
            continue

    logfile(websiteheaders, url)
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant part of the code into the question, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

You need to log the data inside the `for` loop.  You could build a dict as ballsdotballs suggests in his answer, but it seems like just writing to your log each iteration makes more sense unless you need to use the processed information for something other than logging.

```
def headerophalen(websites):

    for url in websites:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
            print "Error opening URL: ", url, "HTTP Errorcode: ", error.code
        else:
            logfile(url, str(response.info()).splitlines())
```

Comment: This actually does nothing lol, it will now not do anything, because I do not want to log something in the logfile when it fails opening the URL. After the for loop ( which downloads the headers and puts them into a list ) I want to start a new function called logfile which will do something else with the headers

Comment: I looked over your question again, noticed that, and adjusted my answer accordingly.  There's a deeper flaw in your logic though.  It doesn't make sense to do whatever `logfiles` does with a single URL but the full list of `websiteheaders`.  What are you actually trying to do here?  You also never initialize `websiteheaders`, so it's going to raise an exception when you try to `extend`.

Comment: I do not receive an error when I extend `websiteheaders` because it is beeing initialized at the top of my code. In the logfile function I want to print the URL that was checked, print a timestamp with that and the "Server" line in the header into a logfile.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `logfile(websiteheaders, url)`, url will simply be the last url in your websites array, so that is the only one that will be logged in your log file.  If I were you, I'd save the url->headers information in a dictionary and pass that to your log file.

Try something like:

```
headers = {}
```

And then inside your loop use:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
headerlist = str(response.info())
headers[url] = headerlist.splitlines()
```

Now you have a dictionary where each url has a list of headers.  You can pass that to your log file function and then log it however you wish.

```
logfile(headers)
```

Read up on dictionaries at 
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

edit:fixed my syntax and spelling

Comment: Thanks, I think this should do it, but as I am a nuub in Python, it will take me a couple of days to get this to work into my current logfunction. Because if I just implement this into the for statement it actually does nothing.

Comment: try something like `for k,v in headers.iteritems(): print k,v` and you'll see how you can use it.

Comment: Indeed I see the pairs now, first the URL then the header. Now I just need to find a way to find "Server" value in the headers(values of the dict) and then split them to only print that piece of information...

Comment: Sounds like you're well on your way then.  Cheers mate and welcome to Python!